# this website is trying to load scripts from unauthenticated sources - Google CDN

Tags: html, google-cloud-platform, cdn

I bought a Google cloud network package and installed it in my simplest and uninformed state.
My SSL certificate is corrupted when I try to install it on my own server.

Like this : 33.33.33.33/dog.jpg or http://33.33.33.33/dog.jpg

How do I make http here https_

Comment: You'd need to install a valid SSL certificate on `33.33.33.33`.

Comment: how so? should i buy another ssl certificate

Comment: https://letsencrypt.org/

Comment: If you have purchased an SSL certificate, you can use it in Google Cloud. There are lots of documents on the Internet for setting up SSL. It depends on the software that will be configured (Apache for example).

Comment: Also ming the fact that certificate certifies your control over a host domain. In your example it is just an IP address, but I wouldn't imaging you routinely used it in production/operations.